# Is it possible to find out if a PouchDb index is actively being built

Tags: pouchdb

I understand that it is possible to use the stale option to return less than accurate result while an index is being built. However, I would like to know if there's a way to tell if PouchDb is actively building an index, so that I can notify the user that the result may not be 100% accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to tell that.

But it also doesn't matter, your results will not be inaccurate.  Rather, the query that triggers a re-indexing will block until the index is built.

So your concern to "notify the user that the result may not be 100% accurate" is unfounded.

There is another concern, though, and you can find many discussions of it on SO and elsewhere, and that is that the initial (re-)indexing after mass updates can take a while. To solve this many people suggest doing a dummy query immediately after a bulk update, to get the re-indexing out of the way.  This may or may not apply to your application design.

Comment: _So your concern to "notify the user that the result may not be 100% accurate" is unfounded._ 

The reason why I said that is because according to the API reference [link](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#query_index ), if **stale** is set to **OK**, PouchDB will returns results immediately, even if they’re out-of-date. So, it's possible that it will return matches that have been changed, removed, etc.

Comment: @toyssamurai: That's apparently unique to the pouchdb-find plugin. AFAIK, there's no way to do that with the traditional view queries. If that concerns you, I suggest not setting `stale: ok` :)